# Как написать двойной запрос на SQL?

Tags: sql

Задача: обновить две таблицы одним запрос по определенным ячейкам. Вот код

```
$q = "
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE users SET email='$email',flname='$flname',fllogin='$fllogin',password='$pass',country_code='$country_code' where pk_user = '$userkey';
UPDATE comments,comments_m,comments_f SET email='$email' where id_commenter='$$userkey';
COMMIT;"
```

правильно?

Comment: >> UPDATE comments,comments_m,comments_f SET email='$email';

Вас ничего не смущает ? :)

Comment: Проще всего использовать хранимую процедуру, вызывать передавая параметры

Comment: бездельное не пиши!!!

Comment: нет shuric я просто хочу обновить 3 таблицы они идеинтичны

Comment: @vic использовать хранимую процедуру действительно проще, но как насчет написания и изменения? ;D

Comment: а как насчет повешать триггер на обновление одной из таблиц, чтоб автоматически обновляло 2 другие?

Answer (score 3):

Нельзя обновить две таблицы одним sql-запросом. Попробуйте использовать транзакции.

Answer (score 0):

так вот что-ли =)

```
  UPDATE users SET email='$email',flname='$flname',fllogin='$fllogin',password='$pass',country_code='$country_code' where pk_user = '$userkey'"
    and
    "UPDATE comments SET email='$email' name='$flname'"
```